# File Upload and input text fields together

Tags: php, html

I have file upload and text input fields in my form and what I want is to show the error message for file upload on same page and don't go to the next page if there is error...if there is error on file upload return also the values of text fields to the same page... How I do it?

```
<form action="send.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="submited" value="true" /><br>
<label for="file">Choose Photo:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" required><br>
First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" required><br>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" required><br>
Choose Username:<input type="text" name="username" required><br>
Age:<input type="text" name="age" required><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the php code for file upload....I will be inserting the data from `<input type="text">` to database and I don't have the code for it now...

```
    <?php
ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
if(isset($_REQUEST['submited'])) {

// your save code goes here

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "";

if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
echo "<font color='red'><b>We are sorry, the file you trying to upload already exists.</b></font>";
  }

else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo "<font color='green'><b> Success! Your photo has been uploaded.</b></font>";
}
}
}
else
{
echo "<font color='red'><b>We are sorry, the file you trying to upload is not an image or it exceeds 2MB in size.</b></font><br><font color='blue'><i>Only images under size of 2MB are allowed</i></font>.";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Personally, I would wrap the PHP in a function and make the file upload call with AJAX which would allow for javascript to parse the response (return statement). Then you could use javascript to display that error if it occurs as well as have asynchronous uploading instead of vanilla file uploading!

Answer (score 1):

Just get your PHP to regenerate the form with the fields filled in (i.e. sst the value attribute) in the event of an error.

Answer (score 0):

Heey,

To keep it on the same page u can remove the action

> send.php

And then add the html and php code showed here in the same file. When that file is executed it will stay on the same page.

Comment: I can do that but the problem is that it sends the text data to database whether the Image is uploaded successfully or not..I want the data from the text fields to be sent along with the image..if the there is error uploading image the text data won't be sent to database

Comment: If i understand what u mean u can try this: if($_FILES['logo']['name'] == "") {
// No file was selected for upload, your (re)action goes here
}

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST)){
        //send.php code
    }
?>

<form action="send.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="submited" value="true" /><br>
    <label for="file">Choose Photo:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" required><br>
    First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" required><br>
    Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" required><br>
    Choose Username:<input type="text" name="username" required><br>
    Age:<input type="text" name="age" required><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```